# Odds of guessing exactly n items in a sequence

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Someone is guessing the order of $n$ competitors in a race, no ties. What are the odds that he guesses exactly $k$ places right?

Lets suppose there are A, B, C, D, E, F competitors, and they finished in this order: ABCDEF.

Then $n = 6$, all possible outcomes are $6!$.

- $k=6$ there is $1$ case 
  He guessed the right outcome. (eg. ABCDEF)
- $k=5$ there is $0$ case 
  You can't have $5$ right guesses because if you guessed $5$ right, it means the remaining number is also in the right place.
- $k=4$ there are ${6 \choose 4}$ cases 
  as you can select the four right places and swap the remaining two. (eg. ABCDFE)
- $k=3$ there are ${6 \choose 3} \cdot 2$ cases 
  as you can select the three right places and can shuffle the remaining three in two ways where each is in the wrong place (eg. ABCFDE)
- $k=2$ there are ${6 \choose 2} \cdot 3^2$ cases 
  as you can select the two right places and choose from 3 and again choose from 3, the order of the remaining two is determined (eg. ABFCDE)
- $k=1$ is where things get tricky. There are ${6 \choose 1} \cdot 4 \cdot 2 + {6 \choose 1} \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$ cases, the first term coming from when you swap two and shuffle the rest, the second term coming from shuffling all. 
   (eg. ECDBFA)

Now for $k=0$ I'm having a hard time coming up with the formula. Can someone please give me a deeper insight into this problem with the general formulas and eg. an explanation for $n=8, k=1$?

|  | $k=n$ | $k=n-1$ | $k=n-2$ | $k=n-3$ | $k=n-4$ | $k=n-5$ | $k=n-6$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $n=3$ | 1 | 0 | 3 | 2 | - | - | - |
| $n=4$ | 1 | 0 | 6 | 8 | 9 | - | - |
| $n=5$ | 1 | 0 | 10 | 20 | 45 | 44 | - |
| $n=6$ | 1 | 0 | 15 | 40 | 135 | 264 | 265 |

I have also made a script that calculates the cases, here is the table for the number of cases for some $(n,k)$ pairs.

Comment: The ones he doesn't guess need to be in a derangement, which means no matches. There is a wikipage on derangements.

Comment: Alright, many thanks! Haven't heard about derangements, and I couldn't wrap my head around this.

Comment: You should specify that you are assuming all orders to be equally likely.  In an actual competition, like a horse race, that would be a terrible assumption.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A098825 and https://oeis.org/A098825, and for the hinted 'derangements' see https://oeis.org/A000166

Comment: @lulu Well, of course, but since I haven't mentioned any weighted probability, I thought this is self-evident.